# Programmatically delete a TFS branch

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I want to programmatically delete a branch in TFS that was create automatically.

There is an existing method "ICommonStructureService.DeleteBranches" that should do the work. 
My problem is that the method requires a parameter "string[] nodeUris" that specifies the branch to delete using a "vstfs://... " URI and I just don't know how to get that for my branch.

What I need is something like:

```cs
var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri <myCollectionUrl>));
var cssService = projectCollection.GetService<ICommonStructureService3>();
var project = cssService.GetProjectFromName(<myProjectName>);
```

But how can I get the Branch Uri from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I found a solution. For deleting the branches I am using

```cs
versionControl.Destroy(new ItemSpec(myBranchPath, RecursionType.Full), VersionSpec.Latest,  null, DestroyFlags.KeepHistory);
```

This does exactly what I needed. 
versionControl is of type VersionControlServer and must be initialized using the Team Collection

Comment: `Destroy`?  Programmatically?  Why use version control at all if you're going to destroy everything?

Comment: note that there are DestroyFlags avaialble. "DestroyFlags.KeepHistory" means that not everything is destroyed, but the History is kept. 
The use case for this is e.g. a "temporary" branch that might not be needed later on (in case the history is not destroyed). 
Programmatically because we have an integrated environment that encapsulates many operations of TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a branch in version control is like deleting any other version control item.  You will need to pend a delete with [`Workspace.PendDelete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139358.aspx) on the `Item`.

The [method you reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.server.icommonstructureservice.deletebranches%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is wholly unrelated to version control, it's part of the TFS [common structure service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb169225.aspx), which controls the "[areas and iterations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms181692.aspx)" that TFS work items can be assigned to.

In short, there's no way to perform any sort of version control operations against the common structure service.  You delete a branch by creating a `Workspace` against a `VersionControlServer`, pending a delete and then checking in your pending changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but because there is this method "ICommonStructureService.DeleteBranches", there should be an option to use it.

Comment: There is an option to use it, but not for version control branches, for common structure service branches.  `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.server.icommonstructureservice.deletebranches(v=vs.90).aspx`.

Comment: I do not completely understand what you mean with "common structure services branches". Your link does not seem to work for me ...

Comment: I attempted to clarify my answer.  Please let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to Edward Thomson about using Destroy command. So I followed on advice from him and came up with following,

```cs
public void DeleteBranch(string path)
{
    var vcs = GetVersionControlServer();
    var itemSpec = new ItemSpec(path, RecursionType.Full);
    var itemSpecs = new[] {itemSpec};
    var workSpace = GetOrCreateWorkSpace(vcs);
    try
    {
        workSpace.Map(path, @"c:\Temp\tfs");
        var request = new GetRequest(itemSpec, VersionSpec.Latest);
        workSpace.Get(request, GetOptions.GetAll | GetOptions.Overwrite);
        workSpace.PendDelete(path, RecursionType.Full);
        var pendingchanges = workSpace.GetPendingChanges(itemSpecs);
        workSpace.CheckIn(pendingchanges, "Deleting The Branch");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (workSpace != null)
        {
            workSpace.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

If there is a neat way to do the same than I am looking forward to it. This is bit slow as it does too many things,

- Creates Temp Workspace
- Gets All changes to that
- Performs Delete to whole change set
- checks it in
- Cleans up the workspace