# Removing iteration in VSTS/TFS using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

I use this code to create a new iteration on VSTS/TFS programatically:

```
var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri, tfsCredential);
var service = tfs.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();
var iterationRoot = service.GetNodeFromPath("\\TeamProjectName\\Iteration");
var iteration = service.CreateNode("Sprint 1", iterationRoot.Uri);
```

Now I want to remove an iteration but there is no corresponding method on `ICommonStructureService`. Oddly there is a method named `GetDeletedNodesXml()`.

Comment: Accorthing to [this (rather old) blog post](https://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-deal-with-areas-or-iterations.html) _"How to delete area (or iteration)? First, you need to get area/iteration URI (and that is covered in the beginning of the post). Next, you need to call method DeleteBranches of ICommonStructureService."_ but then goes on to say that it isn't obvious what to pass for the second parameter.

Comment: @stuartd This second parameter must be the path to the iteration which should be applied to all items in the deleted iteration if any. It still does not work complaining on malformed URI. Even wrapping the Uri by `VersionControlPath.GetFullPath()` won't work here. Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833083/programmatically-delete-a-tfs-branch which seems to work (have security issues there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! I'm assuming here that you have some method to retrieve an iteration.

```cs
var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri, tfsCredential);
var service = tfs.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();
// TODO var iteration = GetIteration();    
var projectInfo = service.GetProjectFromName(projectName)
var nodes = service.ListStructures(projectInfo.Uri);
service.DeleteBranches(iteration.Id, nodes[0].Uri);
```

The key is to pass in Ids and not paths. TFS wants to retrieve artifact URLs which are represented as Ids. The second parameter of `DeleteBranches` is the artifact URL of the iteration-root which is obtained by calling `ListStructures` of the `ICommonStructureService` and taking the first element there (which is kind of nasty IMHO but I don't know a better way).